# Is it enough to set Binding Mode in ItemsSource?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding, binding-mode

Is this redundant (`Mode=OneTime` in each `TextBlock`) ?

```
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResultsItems, Mode=OneTime}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Price, Mode=OneTime}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=OneTime}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Setting `ItemsSource` to *OneTime* concerns the collection of item, not the items themselves. `ItemsSource` = *OneTime* really means "if item collection change after initializing, do not update my ListBox".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

If the binding on the itemssource is  mode OneTime you shouldn't get a property change when you change the list (add or remove items) but you'll still get property changes from the properties of the list items.

So if you don't want to display price or description changes on your items you should keep Mode=OneTime on the textblocks.